# How to build and serialize

Tags: apex, json, collection, serialization

[Keith C's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/166174/10073) builds the following "config" output:

```
   config: {option1: {isActive: true, isRequired: true},
             option2: {isActive: true, isRequired: true}
         }
```

by looping customobject data, building the structure in apex, and serializing it:

```
    //The loop in Keith's answer below builds the "config" output
// by serializing nested maps:
         Map<String, Object> m = new Map<String, Object>();
        for (options__C opt:options) {
            m.put(opt.Name__c, new Map<String, Boolean>{
                    'isActive' => opt.isActive__c,
                    'isRequired' => opt.isRequired__c
                    });
        }
        return JSON.serialize(m);
```

That works fine, but **how would we modify Keith's answer to build the following different "config" structure?:**
In other words using Apex and a `for (options__C opt:options) {...}` loop , how would we build the following "config" structure?:

```
config: {
        allSettings : [
            {'isActive': opt.isActive__c, 'isRequired':opt.isRequired__c}, //options[0]
            {'isActive': opt.isActive__c, 'isRequired':opt.isRequired__c}, //options[1]
            {'isActive': opt.isActive__c, 'isRequired':opt.isRequired__c} //options[2]
        ]
    }
```

My attempt:

```
    for (options__C opt:options) {
    //options.size() == 3
//unsure how to build this into the 'allSettings' structure...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing via maps can get very confusing and convoluted very quickly.

Any time I need to come up with a specific format for serialization, I either write the Apex classes by hand or head on over to Json2Apex and plug my structure in, and have it generate the Apex classes I need based on the JSON structure I give it.

You can try  it for yourself: [Json2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/)

If you plug in the desired structure above you should get something similar to:

```
 public class ConfigContainer{
    public Config config {get; set;}
}

public class Config{
    public Setting[] allSettings {get; set;}
}

public class Setting{
    public boolean isActive {get; set;}
    public boolean isRequired {get; set;}
}
```

When you have the desired structure, then it's just a matter of plugging it in and generating the correct objects:

```
public class MyOptionsGenerator{

    public static String getMyOptionsString(){

        ConfigContainer cc = new ConfigContainer();
        cc.config = new Config();

        cc.config.allSettings = new List<Setting>();
        for(Options__c opt : options){
            cc.config.allSettings.add(new Setting(opt));
        }

        //Serialize the return type.
        return JSON.serialize(cc);
   }

    public class ConfigContainer{
        public Config config {get; set;}
    }

    public class Config{
        public List<Setting> allSettings {get; set;}
    }

    public class Setting{
        public boolean isActive {get; set;}
        public boolean isRequired {get; set;}

        public Setting(Options__c opt){
            this.isActive = opt.IsActive__c;
            this.isRequired = opt.isRequired__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi James, I havent tested this yet but it looks accurate and does address my question so I am accepting the answer.  Thank you sir!